# object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: unity, c#

hello i have a error "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

when my ball collide with the spikes.its supose to remove one heart but it doesnt.

***health code:***

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Health : MonoBehaviour {
  public int health;
  public int numOfHearts;

  public Image[] hearts;
  public Sprite fullHeart;




  // Use this for initialization
  void Start () {

  }

  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update () {
    if (health > numOfHearts)
    {
      health = numOfHearts;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < hearts.Length; i++)
    {
      if (i < health)
      {
        hearts[i].sprite = fullHeart;
      }
      if (i < numOfHearts)
      {
        hearts[i].enabled = true;
      }
      else
      {
        hearts[i].enabled = false;
      }
    }

  }
  public void Damage(int dmg)
  {
    numOfHearts -= dmg;
  }
}
```

***spikes code:***

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spikes : MonoBehaviour {

  private Health Player;


  // Use this for initialization
  void Start () {
    Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Health>();


  }

  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update () {

  }

  void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
  {
    if (col.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
      Player.Damage(1); // here i have the error.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [gamedev.se]! We have a go-to question for this type of error. I hope it will help you find out what is causing the error.

Comment: where are you getting this exception in your code?